# Django rest framework reflect true REST API for function based view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have three models: A 'User' will have a 'Wishlist' and a 'Wishlist' will have many 'Books'.

To perform CRUD operations on Wishlist, I am writing my URLs and corresponding views. Right now I have one url:

```
url(r'^wishlist/$', wishlist),
```

and a function:

```
# Get specific user's wishlist
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def wishlist(request):
    """
    List all the books in wishlist of a specific user/Update/add/delete
    """

    if request.method == 'GET':
        books = Book.objects.filter(wishlist__user=request.user)
        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data) 

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        ... 

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        ...

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        ...
```

*My question is*- having such one function with one url and all four methods is a correct way to build true REST API, or should I separate them? Considering for example, for `PUT` and `DELETE` methods, I perhaps also could send wishlist_id in the url and handle accordingly. In current code snippet, I will have to filter against `request.user`

Comment: No, this isn't the right way at all. Have you read the whole of the DRF tutorial? That will eventually show you how to use viewsets for this.

Comment: Why dont you use the DRF ModelViewSet, it handles CRUD for you....